# How to match only if the both brackets are there in the string?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
^[-+(]?\d+([,.]\d+)*([\)])*$
```

I am using the above regular expression for matching strings. one case i need to check

Testing string :

`(111,1,1,1.3.3` should be failed

```
(111,1,1,1.3.3)  should be passed
+1.1.1.1,1       should be passed
-1111            should be passed
-2,2,2,2.4.4     should be passed
2,3              should be passed
```

The above string is matching the regex, but i want to check if the string contains first bracket it should check for end match with bracket.

Comment: You cannot express that in JavaScript (with a single regular expression) (well, I guess you can but only with repetition).

Comment: You need to accept answers to old questions before moving on with the new question

Comment: @vks instead of accept,I clicked up vote..now accepted answer..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ored` regex here.

```
^(?:[+-]?\(\d+([,.]\d+)*\)|[+-]?\d+([,.]\d+)*)$
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/19

Comment: answer from the above link :                                                                  `/^(?:\(\d+([,.]\d+)*\)|[+-]?\d+([,.]\d+)*)$/gm`

Answer (score 0):

try this regex:

```js
function validate(){
  var regex = /^[-+(]?\d+([,.]\d+)*([\)])+/gi;
  var value = document.getElementById("txtInput").value;
  console.log(value);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = regex.test(value); 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtInput" value="(111,1,1,1.3.3">
<p id="result"></p>
<button onclick="validate()">Validate</button>
```